# Aligning ngForm Contents in Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

I have some fields in my ngForm. All the labels and inputs are aligned in a straight line(vertically).
I want it to be in form of two columns, like "Prescription details" on the right, and "Symptoms" on the left. Date on the right hand side corner.

I tried different styles like position and text-align but none of them worked.

Here's the code:

```html
<div class="row">

        <div class="column" style="padding: 7.5%" >
            <form #institutesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="instituteLogins(institutesForm)">
                    <div class="form-group">
        <label> <strong>Date</strong> </label>
        <input type="date"   name="date" id="date"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="institutes.date">
        <br>
        <h2> <strong> Patient Problems</strong></h2>
        
        <label><strong> Symtoms</strong> </label>
        <input type="text"  name="symtoms" id="symtoms"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.symtoms">
        <label><strong>Allergy</strong>  </label>
        <input type="text"  name="allergy" id="allergy"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.allergy">
        <br>
        <h2><strong>Diagnosis</strong></h2>
        
        <label> <strong>Condition</strong> </label>
        <input type="text"  name="condition" id="condition"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.condition">
        <label><strong> Advice </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="advice" id="advice"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.advice">
        <br>
        <h2> <strong>Prescription</strong> </h2>
        <br>
        <label><strong> Medication </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="medication" id="medication"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.medication">
        <label><strong>Course</strong></label>
        <input type="text"  id="course" name="course"  class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.course">
        <br><br>
        
                    </div>
                    <button id="record" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Add Record</button> </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: This is how it looks now]

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can visit this link: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_stacked_to_hor&stacked=h and adjust your columns accordingly. You will get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I'm not exactly sure about what you mean in terms of the specifics of the layout but all in all I feel you should phase out bootstrap and use `CSS Grid` which allows us to define our own grids as well as designated areas of that grid which we can use to constrain our elements to those defined spaces.  I made a simple demo for you to look at [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z8bzct) to see how the `div`s are being constrained to certain portions of the page by their classes.  You can create grids on your sub elements as well.  It will make life a lot easier on you and your code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting ngForm elements positions is a difficult task in a single class.

Using multiple classes="column/row" and aligning those classes vertically / horizontally helped me.

```html
<div >
    <h1>
        New Patient Record
    </h1>
    <button (click)="append()" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 70%;">Prescribe more medicines</button>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 0px;">
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column">
<label > <strong>Date</strong> </label>
<input type="date"   name="date" id="date"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="institutes.date">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:0px" >
        <div class="container" style="padding-left: 7.5%" >
            <form #institutesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="instituteLogins(institutesForm)">
                    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="column">             
                                            
                       
        <h2><strong> Symptoms</strong> </h2>
        <input type="text"  name="symptoms" id="symptoms"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.symptoms">
        
        <br>
        <h2><strong>Diagnosis</strong></h2>
        
        <label> <strong>Condition</strong> </label>
        <input type="text"  name="condition" id="condition"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.condition">
        <label><strong> Advice </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="advice" id="advice"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.advice">
        <br>
        
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <h2> <strong>Prescription</strong> </h2>
        <br>
        <label><strong> Medication </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="medication" id="medication"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.medication">
        <label><strong> Medicine Type </strong></label>
        <input type="text"  name="type" id="type"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.type">
        <label><strong>Course</strong></label>
        <input type="text"  id="course" name="course"  class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.course">
        <label><strong> How many per day? </strong></label>
        
        
        <input type="text"  name="cday" id="cday"   class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.cday">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column">
        <button id="record"  class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Add Record</button>
    </div>
</div>
   
       </div>
        <br><br>
        
                    </div>
                     </form>
                    
    </div>
```